# PWA icons are not used in iOS 11.3

Tags: mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

Now I'm testing PWA on iOS 11.3 and I use the manifest.json file below:

```
{
  "name": "Maplat PWA Sample",
  "short_name": "Maplat PWA",
  "background_color": "#fc980c",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "/Maplat/pwa/icon-96.png",
    "sizes": "96x96",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "/Maplat/pwa/icon-144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "/Maplat/pwa/icon-192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "/Maplat/pwa/icon-256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "start_url": "/Maplat/debug.html?overlay=true",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

This works well except icon setting.
In my iOS 11.3 on iPhoneX, icon files are not shown on home screen but screen capture is used as launcher button.

I compared my manifest with other sites, like https://www.ft.com/ or https://r.nikkei.com/, but I couldn't find any differences in icon settings.
Icons of these sites work well with PWA on iOS 11.3.

What is wrong in my manifest.json?

P.S. My manifest.json works well with Android Chrome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**2022 Update**:

Declaring icons in a web app manifest file [is now supported](https://webkit.org/blog/12445/new-webkit-features-in-safari-15-4/#web-apps).
However `purpose` value should contain `any` (e.g. `"any maskable"`) or omitted completely. Otherwise it won't work.

`SVG` format is still not supported, but `PNG` or `WebP` could be used instead.

Answer (score 100):

While iOS 11.3 does support web app manifests, it does not yet support specifying icons this way. You'll want to include it in your manifest for other devices, but at least for now you'll have to use the following for iOS:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icon.png">
```

Specify the icon size, and include a URL.

Learn more at [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

There is also a website to automate the process [linked here](https://realfavicongenerator.net)

Comment: > it does not yet support specifying icons this way
Oh is it..I don't know it, thank you it helps me!

Comment: FYI, when testing my PWA on localhost with a dummy SSL certificate, Safari won't use the icon when adding to homescreen. Instead it takes a screenshot of the page as the icon. Once the PWA was uploaded to the live server, with full HTTPS, the icon worked fine. Testing on iOS11.3,  iPad 6th gen.

Comment: can I also specify the background color of icon ?

Comment: To complement this, as of iOS 14, there's no support for manifest icons. Source: https://firt.dev/ios-14/

Answer (score 14):

TerPro's answer is correct but as a fallback you can put a file named "/apple-touch-icon.png" in the root directory.