# How to set icon on PWA app on home screen and Bookmark using nuxt.config.js (Safari)

Tags: javascript, safari, manifest, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I'm developing PWA app using Nuxt.js.
I could launch it well , So I tried to add HomeScreen and Bookmark by Safari (iOS11.4).
However icon weren't shown on home screen and bookmark.(Google Chrome and Android work well)

nuxt.config.js is bellow

```js
const pkg = require('./package')
const dir = "/dir/"

module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content: 'yes' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content:'black'},
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-title', content:"test"},
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/favicon.ico` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` }
    ]
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  router:{
    base:`${dir}/`,
    mode:"history",
    middleware:[
      'auth'
    ]   
  },
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/onsenui',
    '~/plugins/axios',
    '~/plugins/routerOption'
  ],
  manifest: {
      name: "test",
      lang: 'ja',
      'display':'fullscreen',
      title:'test',
      'og:title':'test',
      description:'test',
      'og:description':'test',
      theme_color:'#FFFFFF',
      background_color:'#FFFFFF',
      start_url:`${dir}/`,
      short_name:"test",
      icons:[{
        src:`${dir}/icon.png`,
        size:"144x144",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/icon.png`,
        size:"192x192",
        type:"image/png"
      }]
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa', 
    ['@nuxtjs/moment', ['ja']],
    defaultLocale: 'ja',
  ],    
  workbox: {
    dev: true 
  },
  axios:{
    proxy:true
  }
}
```

What went wrong ?
Somebody teach me how to fix it pls :)

P.S.
Here is static folder directory.

static
    -icon.png
    -favicon.ico

And I tried this but it didn't work.

```
   const pkg = require('./package')
const dir = "/dir/"

module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content: 'yes' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content:'black'},
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-title', content:"test"},
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/favicon.ico` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"57x57", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"60x60", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"72x72", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"76x76", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"114x114", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"120x120", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"144x144", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"152x152", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon',sizes:"180x180", href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` }

    ]
  },
  manifest: {
      name: "test",
      lang: 'ja',
      'display':'fullscreen',
      title:'test',
      'og:title':'test',
      description:'test',
      'og:description':'test',
      theme_color:'#FFFFFF',
      background_color:'#FFFFFF',
      start_url:`${dir}/`,
      short_name:"test",
      icons:[{
        src:`${dir}/icon.png`,
        size:"144x144",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/icon.png`,
        size:"180x180",
        type:"image/png"
      }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve by myself using PWACompat.

It worked well as bellow.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content: 'yes' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content:'black'},
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-title', content:"test"},
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/favicon.ico` }
    ],
    script:[
      {
      src:"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pwacompat@2.0.6/pwacompat.min.js",
        integrity:"sha384-GOaSLecPIMCJksN83HLuYf9FToOiQ2Df0+0ntv7ey8zjUHESXhthwvq9hXAZTifA",
        crossorigin:"anonymous" ,defer:true
      }
    ]
  },
  manifest: {
      name: "test",
      lang: 'ja',
      // 'display':'standalone',
      title:'test',
      'og:title':'test',
      description:'test',
      'og:description':'test',
      theme_color:'#FFFFFF',
      background_color:'#FFFFFF',
      start_url:`${dir}/`,
      short_name:"test",
      icons:[{
        src:`${dir}/icon.png`,
        size:"144x144",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png`,
        size:"128x128",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png`,
        size:"152x152",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png`,
        size:"180x180",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png`,
        size:"192x192",
        type:"image/png"
      },{
        src:`${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png`,
        size:"256x256",
        type:"image/png"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for watching and answering !:)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your file inside the static nuxt folder (static)

an load all your file simply from the root path.

```
      <!-- Static image from static directory -->
      <img src="/my-image.png"/>
```

See the docs =>

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/ .

Thanks

Comment: HI Birante . 
Thank you for comment and sorry for I didn't inform you what is my static folder going on. 
I ready files in the static folder like bellow .  
/static/favicon.ico
/static/apple-touch-icon.png

However it didn't work yet ..

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568333/pwa-icons-are-not-used-in-ios-11-3), iOS 11.3 does support web app manifests, it does not yet support specifying icons this way. You'll want to include it in your manifest for other devices, but at least for now you'll have to use the following for iOS:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icon.png">
```

You must specify the icon size, and include a URL.

Kindly check this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Comment: Hi jess, Thank you for comment . 
I tried that but It didn't work unfortunately .
icon.png what I prepare and store in static folder  should be 180x180 size?
I stored icon.png(size:192x192) then I wrote bellow but it didn't work well.


 link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/favicon.ico` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` },
      { rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: `${dir}/apple-touch-icon.png` sizes:"180x180" }
    ]